# How to access bokeh server running within a docker container

Tags: python, docker, bokeh, plotly-dash

***I have checked the related answers before but still could not make it***

I have a dash app that should run a bokeh server in the docker container. The code works fine in my local and I can reach plots via `http://localhost:5006/simple_bokeh_example`
However, I built the docker file and did the same, bokeh server started I could not see it like above because localhost refers to the host. I tried to add a flask route inside the dash which communicates with the bokeh server. I tried docker commands, ..etc.

How can I see the plots this time? Could you PLEASE give me a running example by changing my code, or you can introduce your one as well? I could not find any working examples. What I found are just explanations(all good they are perfect. Not saying they are useless), or vague suggestions. I am sure a simple but working example would be really helpful for others going forward.

Thanks!

**Dash App(bokeh_test.py)**

```
import dash
from dash import html
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output
import subprocess

app = dash.Dash(__name__)

app.layout = html.Div([
    html.Button("Open Bokeh Example", id="open-bokeh-button"),
    html.Div(id="output")
])


@app.callback(
    Output("output", "children"),
    Input("open-bokeh-button", "n_clicks")
)
def open_bokeh_example(n_clicks):
    if n_clicks is not None and n_clicks > 0:
        try:
            subprocess.run("bokeh serve --show simple_bokeh_example.py",
                           shell=True, capture_output=True, text=True)

            return html.Div([f"Bokeh example opened."])
        except Exception as e:
            return html.Div([f"Error opening Bokeh example: {str(e)}"])
    return ""


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run_server(debug=True, host="0.0.0.0")
```

**Bokeh(simple_bokeh_example.py)**

```
from random import random
from bokeh.layouts import column
from bokeh.models import Button
from bokeh.palettes import RdYlBu3
from bokeh.plotting import figure, curdoc

p = figure(x_range=(0, 100), y_range=(0, 100), toolbar_location=None)
p.border_fill_color = 'black'
p.background_fill_color = 'black'
p.outline_line_color = None
p.grid.grid_line_color = None

r = p.text(x=[], y=[], text=[], text_color=[], text_font_size="26px",
           text_baseline="middle", text_align="center")

i = 0

ds = r.data_source


def callback():
    global i

    new_data = dict()
    new_data['x'] = ds.data['x'] + [random() * 70 + 15]
    new_data['y'] = ds.data['y'] + [random() * 70 + 15]
    new_data['text_color'] = ds.data['text_color'] + [RdYlBu3[i % 3]]
    new_data['text'] = ds.data['text'] + [str(i)]
    ds.data = new_data

    i = i + 1


button = Button(label="Press Me")
button.on_event('button_click', callback)

curdoc().add_root(column(button, p))
```

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM python:3.9-slim
WORKDIR /app
COPY . /app
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
EXPOSE 8050
CMD ["python", "bokeh_test.py"]
```

Comment: The repository for the hosted demo site uses a docker container: https://github.com/bokeh/demo.bokeh.org There are instructions to run in the README (you can ignore all the terraform parts of the repo, which are specific to our AWS infrastructure).

Comment: Note since you are running in a subprocess, you'll need to configure your invocation of `bokeh serve` via `subprocess.run` similarly to what's in that Dockerfile, e.g. allow all websocket origins (or if you are able, be more specific than "*") and of couse, you will need to expose the Bokeh server's port (by defaultl port 5006)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Mine is dash app. There are 4 tabs in it. The last tab has a button that runs the bokeh server. As far as I understand dockerfile you mentioned is designed for bokeh app. Correct?

Comment: It is designed to run a single `bokeh serve` (and open the relevant Bokeh server port) directly from the Dockerfile. Your usage seems a bit more involved and I don't have any directly comparable example to share.